# How to duplicate a folder and its content with a form

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am currently working on a project with CodeIgniter 3 with HMVC. I would like to know if it is possible to duplicate and rename a folder and rename the the files in the subfolders with the help of PHP.

To show what I mean. Here is a folder I would like to duplicate:

```
* mainfolder
    * controllers
        * Mainfolder.php
    * views
        * mainfolder_view.php
```

So when I submit a form I would like to duplicate it and rename the files like
this:

```
* duplicate
    * controllers
        * Duplicate.php
    * views
        * duplicate_view.php
```

Hopefully someone can give me some tips or directions how to achieve this and thanks for all the all help in advance.

Comment: use a recursive directory iterator (https://secure.php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) and copy your desired files  to the given destination - shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: is there any reason you can't use http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php?